# Format MySQL code in Markdown/Macdown editors

Tags: mysql, editor, markdown

I'm trying to find out which is the smartest way for render some pieces of MySQL queries with [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)/[Macdown](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/) editors.

I have tried to apply 4 spaces with `˜˜˜sql` markup before the query code snippet but it seems not working well because it doesn't show code highlights.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Did you read the [Code Blocks](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) section? In any case, it appears to be a project abandoned like 13 years ago, don't expect too much sophistication.

Comment: What about Macdown editor? It seems more recent and constantly updated as project. A generic code snipped would be formatted with 4 spaces but I think there is a way for tell to the editor which is the language used for highilight better some parts of the code.

Comment: Docs for that appear to be [here](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/features/) and [here](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/features/code-block-highlighting/). Make sure you check all the appropriate ckeckboxes. I can't tell much more, I don't even have a Mac.

Comment: I have already seen those doc pages for Macdown. The problem is that I'm not able to format them for sql, even if I put sql language ID before the code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **I have tried to apply [four] spaces with `~~~sql` markup before the ... code snippet**

In Brief:

- Don't mix indentation and code fencing
- Check the options in your markdown processor
- Make sure you use enough tilde characters, `~~~` is not enough, `~~~~` is.

---

Longer answer:

#### 1. Don't mix indentation and code-fencing

You must choose between indented code blocks and fenced code blocks. Partial mixtures of alternative syntaxes won't work.

```
# Code Block #

What follows is a fenced code block. 
Note that all text starts immediately in the left margin. 
There is no indentation of the fences. 
There are no extra space characters at the start of these lines.

~~~~sql
update employee
  set salary = salary * 2
  where salary < 100000
~~~~

The following will not work

    ~~~~sql
    update employee
      set salary = salary * 2
      where salary < 100000
    ~~~~

You cannot mix indentation and fencing.
```

The syntax identifiers are part of the [fenced code block](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/blog/macdown-help/#fenced-code-block) syntax. You **must** also **end** the code block with a line of tildes.

SQL is a [supported language](http://macdown.uranusjr.com/features/code-block-highlighting/) for syntax highlighting.

#### 2. Macdown options

You must also *"tick the Enable highlighting in code blocks option."* in Macdown.

[image: Image of Macdown Preferences dialogue]

#### 3. Number of tilde (~) characters is important

(Note O.P. Ugol eventually noticed this - see comments. Initially we both overlooked it)

`~~~sql` has too few tilde characters, only three

`~~~~sql` has the correct number of tilde characters to indicate a "fenced block"

Comment: Hi @RedGrittyBrick, I have already tried this configuration with 4 spaces and `˜˜˜mysql` identifier as showed in the example page, but it doesn't hightlight some specific parts of code snippet. I have also tried to reproduce the python snippet example and the result was the code formatted but not with highlights.

Comment: Can you show me a concrete example with sql identifier? So I can understand If I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ugol: please update your question to show screenshots of the unrendered markup and the rendered form you get. It would probably help if you use an image editor to add arrows to point at parts where actual output differs from expected.

Comment: did you see the screenshot uploaded?

Comment: @Ugol: clearly, it isn't recognising your markup at all. Do the tildes start at right at the beginning of the line?

Comment: The tildes start at the beginning of the line after 4 spaces, as you can see from the screenshot.

Comment: @Ugol: did you read tha part of my answer where I said "you must choose between ..."

Comment: Yes, but if I remove the four spaces the code ouput doesn't work at 100%. With the four spaces the code output partially works withouth highlights.

Comment: Okay, finally I have understood the problem...... I was putting `~~~` instead of `~~~~`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the highlighting did not work on a Jupyter notebook. By switching to `~~~ mysql` it does work (rather than using `~~~ sql`).